# Access dynamically named JavaScript Objects?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JS Object:

```
var testObj = new Object();
```

that has a property called volume1, so

```
testObj.volume1
```

has a value. How would I go about accessing that property by using something along the lines of

```
testObj.volume + "1"
```

To give it more context, the object actually has more properties, like

```
testObj.volume1, testObj.volume2 and testObj.volume3
```

and I want to access them using some iteration. I've tried playing with the `window[]` element, but have had not much success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   testObj["volume" + 1]
```

but you actually want an array here

```
   testObj.volume = [...]
   testObj.volume[1] = whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

off topic it is considered better pratice to do

```
var testObj = {};
```

instead of

```
var testObj = new Object();
```

Comment: sorry about that, am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Use something in the fashion of `testObj["volume" + "1"]` ;)

The notations `object.property` and `object["property"]` are (almost) equivalent in javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `for` loop with `in` operation.

```
for(var PropName in testObj) {
    var PropValue = testObj[PropName];
    ....
}
```

In case, you only want the property with the name started with 'value' only, you can also do this:

```
for(var PropName in testObj) {
    if (!/^value[0-9]$/.match(PropName))
        continue;
    var PropValue = testObj[PropName];
    ....
}
```

OR if the number after the 'value' is always continuous you can just use a basic for loop.

```
for(var I = 0; I <= LastIndex; I++) {
    var PropName  = "value" + I;
    var PropValue = testObj[PropName];
    ....
}
```

Hope this helps.